# Return object with default values from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider:

```
    const fields = ['email', 'password'];

    const objFields = {};
    fields.forEach(value => {
      objFields[value] = '';
    });

    console.log(objFields);
// Outputs {email: "", password: ""}
```

I want to achieve the same result, but without having to initialize an empty object.

Actually, my case is that I want to set the initial state of a React component.

```
class App extends Component {
  fields = ['email', 'password'];

  state = {

    fields: // The one liner code here that should return the object created from fields array,

  };
  ...
```

The expected result would be

```
// state = {fields: {email: "", password: ""}}
```

Comment: `fields` will have only two values?

Comment: `fields.reduce((acc,k) => (acc[k] = "", acc), {})`

Comment: @brk that is for simplicity purpose in question only

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you're looking for reducing an array of values to one value, you're looking for [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
state = {
  fields: fields.reduce((acc, key) => ({...acc, [key]: ''}), {}),
};
```

Answer (score 7):

In [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=fromEntries), or by [using polyfills](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js), you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create an object from an array, using the array's values as keys/properties, and fill the object's values with a default.

```js
const fields = ['email', 'password'];

const result = Object.fromEntries(fields.map(value => [value, '']));
```

The result is `{email: "", password: ""}`.

Answer (score 5):

You could map objects and assign all to a single object.

```js
const
    fields = ['email', 'password'],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...fields.map(key => ({ [key]: '' })));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform your array which contains keys into a real object.

To do it, you have many possibilities, but you still have to do something. There isn't any magical trick.

My favorite solution is to use a function to insert into your utility class. So it's easy to read and reusable.

---

#### Number 1: The function

```js
function initializeKeys(keys, initialValue, object) {
  return keys.reduce((tmp, x) => {
    tmp[x] = initialValue;

    return tmp;
  }, object);
}

const objFields = initializeKeys(['email', 'password'], '', {
  otherKey: 'a',
});

console.log(objFields);
```

---

#### Number 2: The *forEach*

```js
const fields = ['email', 'password'];

const objFields = {};

fields.forEach(value => {
  objFields[value] = '';
});

console.log(objFields);
```

---

#### Number 3: The [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const fields = ['email', 'password'];

const objFields = {
  ...fields.reduce((tmp, x) => {
    tmp[x] = '';

    return tmp;
  }, {}),
};

console.log(objFields);
```