# Convert array to object keys

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to convert an array, to an object with those array values as keys, empty strings serve as the values of the new object.

```
['a','b','c']
```

to:

```
{
  a: '',
  b: '',
  c: ''
}
```

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by "best way"? the more efficient will be a loop, the shortest text will be a functional approach (and all answers will be functional because it's trendy)

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(['a', 'b', 'c'].map(k => [k, '']));`

Comment: The duplicates here make no sense.

Comment: @Liam The duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218671/return-object-with-default-values-from-array-in-javascript seems to ask the same question.

Comment: Having closed as duplicate against similar but not the same questions, puts the best answer in the comments of the question... great! Thanks @luukvhoudt for commenting!

Comment: Two complainers, but only one vote to reopen.  I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Try with [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
const res = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=> (acc[curr]='',acc),{});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: whatt does returning `(a[b] = '',a)` mean? what does the second argument do?

Comment: @ShivamSahil check now, I have edited the answer. Each time of the loop `current value` inserted into accumulator `acc[curr] = ''` like this. `,acc` is returning the accumulator once loop end. And `,{}` is defined the accumulator is a object

Comment: Could somebody add a Typescript version of this?

Comment: @cbdeveloper typescript version https://www.mycompiler.io/view/AlipcFS

Comment: @ShivamSahil a good explanation of how the comma operator works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 57):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)and [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```js
let arr = ['a','b','c'];
let obj = arr.reduce((ac,a) => ({...ac,[a]:''}),{});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Why do simple when you can do complicated...

Comment: From an eslint point of view this syntax is less ambiguous than the most voted one, +1.

Answer (score 22):

```
const target = {}; ['a','b','c'].forEach(key => target[key] = "");
```

Comment: Why do you use `map` to iterate over an array ? You could have chosen `forEach`

Comment: forEach would work as well.

Comment: Usually [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used to create a new array and the function passed to map is a pure function.

Comment: I don't understand why everybody was trying to complicate everything with reduce when there was such an obvious and simple answer

Comment: @Tofandel because this is perfect and handy usage of `reduce`... `forEach` requires variable declaration, `reduce` is true one-liner and this is kind of task it was designed for. It's definitely not 'complicated'.

Comment: "True one-liners" are just making code more obscure and harder to understand. Better to add one line and have a code you can understand right away

Answer (score 15):

You can use the *Object.assign* property to combine objects created with a map function. Please take into account that, if the values of array elements are not unique, the latter ones will overwrite previous ones.

```js
const array = Object.assign({},...["a","b","c"].map(key => ({[key]: ""})));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function and pass an empty object in the accumulator. In this accumulator, add a key which is denoted by `curr`.

```js
let k = ['a', 'b', 'c']

let obj = k.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc[curr] = '';
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(obj)
```

Another option is to use `for..of` loop

```js
let k = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const obj = {};
for (let keys of k) {
  obj[keys] = '';
 }

console.log(obj)
```