# How to set array to object keys javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this

```
array = ["column1", "column2", "column3"]
```

and this other

```
array = ["infor1", "infor2", infor3"]
```

I would like to do this:

```
{
  column1: infor1,
  column2: infor2,
  column3: infor3
}
```

Comment: We expect a little bit of effort, please show what you have tried to achieve your objective.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Google is your friend. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789406/convert-array-to-object-keys

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice that. @MikeK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var array1 = ["column1", "column2", "column3"]

var array2 = ["infor1", "infor2", "infor3"]

var obj = {};
array1.forEach(function(y, z) {
  obj[y] = array2[z];

});
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do something like this,

```
const props = ["column1", "column2", "column3"];
const values = ["infor1", "infor2", "infor3"];

props.reduce((acc, itm, i) => (acc[itm] = values[i], acc) , {});
```

You can read more about .reduce [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: @carlosSanchez You can refer the question that was used to duplicate your question . But this is a complete answer.

Comment: short and neat  answer