# Javascript: Convert Array into Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have array:

```
[
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'h', 'k'],
  ['c', 'd', 'e']
]
```

Is there a best way to convert it on object like this?

```
{
  a: [
       ['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['a', 'h', 'k'],
     ],
  c: [
       ['c', 'd', 'e']
     ]
}
```

Comment: what is the rule to convert? ask the question clearly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54789452/15064340 check this

Comment: You can use any of the grouping questions like ([Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511) or [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697)). Use `'0'` as the property you want to group by.

Comment: it is to merge all the ways elements have an equal array [0] into one key of the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'h', 'k'],
  ['c', 'd', 'e']
];

const result = data.reduce((r, c) => {
  r[c[0]] = r[c[0]] || [];
  r[c[0]].push(c);
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You should cache the `c[0]` into an individual variable named `key` to make your code less complex as well as avoid duplication codes :)  Is that ok if I edit it? sir

Comment: Also, you can make your code more concise like from `r[c[0]] = r[c[0]] || [];` to `acc[key] ??= [];`. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66024352/9071943) below if you like. Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) & [`Logical nullish assignment (??=)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const arrays = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'h', 'k'],
  ['c', 'd', 'e']
];

const result = arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const key = curr[0];
  acc[key] ??= [];
  acc[key].push(curr);
  
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```