# Convert array of strings into an object with those string as properties and null values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have this:

```
const myArr = ["NAME_A","NAME_B","NAME_C"];
```

And I'd like to convert it to:

```
const myObj = {
  NAME_A: null,
  NAME_B: null,
  NAME_C: null,
}
```

I can do it by initializing an empty object and adding properties by iterating the array with `forEach` or something, but I believe there is a more efficient solution out there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert array to object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789406/convert-array-to-object-keys)

Comment: @Aristotle Yes!

Comment: Nina will come up with something, hold on

Comment: one loop using each index value of the array as a key for the new object seems to work *shrugs*

Answer (score 0):

```js
//I just used the indexes in the array as keys in the object *shrugs*
function arrToObj(arr){ //converting function
  let obj={}
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    obj[arr[i]]=null
  }
  return obj
}

const myArr = ["NAME_A","NAME_B","NAME_C"];
const myObj=arrToObj(myArr)
console.log(myObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline queries to entries and create object from this entries like

Object.fromEntries(["NAME_A","NAME_B","NAME_C"].map((x)=>[x, null]))