# Advanced in converting arrays to objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, converters

I'm struggling with the following javascript problem.
Is there any way to do it like this?

```html
// input, based on this data, I want the output to be like below
const ListValues = ["id", "name", "description"]

// output
const initialValues = {
    id: "",
    name: "",
    description: "",
};
```

Thank you so much and Have a good day <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create your desired object from the input.

```js
const ListValues = ["id", "name", "description"];

const initialValues = Object.fromEntries(ListValues.map(v => [v, '']));

console.log('initialValues:', initialValues)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could also use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the same result:

```js
const ListValues = ["id", "name", "description"];

const initialValues = ListValues.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
    acc[cur] = '';
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log('initialValues:', initialValues)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you vary much, and I also just found more information here, hope it helps the following people

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789406/convert-array-to-object-keys