# Turning two arrays into an object : one array as keys and the other array as values

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:
`[ 'J', 'o', 'h', 'a', 'n']`
`[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]`
I would like to use the first one as the object keys and the second one as object values. The result should be:
`{ "J": 1, "o": 1, "h": 1, "a": 2, "n": 1}`

Is this achievable with JavaScript ?

Comment: How are you supposed to handle duplicate keys? Which value are you supposed to use?

Comment: your result is not valid with duplicate property "a"

Comment: I deleted the duplicated value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an object from an array of keys and an array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/create-an-object-from-an-array-of-keys-and-an-array-of-values)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use `Object.fromEntries()` along with `Array.prototype.map()`] as below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// the initial arrays:
let keys = [ 'J', 'o', 'h', 'a', 'n'],
    entries = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
    // here we use Object.fromEntries() to create
    // an Object from a two-dimensional Array of
    // Arrays:
    result = Object.fromEntries(
      // we use Array.prototype.map() to iterate over
      // the keys Array:
      keys.map(
        // passing a reference to the current Array-value
        // ('key'), and the index of the current Array-
        // value ('index') into the function body.
        // Within the function body we return an Array
        // containing the current Array-element (which
        // becomes a key of the created-Object, and
        // the Array-element from the entries Array
        // at the same index:
        (key, index) => [key,entries[index]]
    ));
    
    console.log(result);
    /*
      {
        "J": 1,
        "o": 1,
        "h": 1,
        "a": 2,
        "n": 1
      }
    */
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/oLhapct3/1/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`Object.prototype.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

Answer (score 1):

As @PCDSandwichMan mentioned you can use reduce. See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Reduce goes through the array and returns a single value. It can sometimes be littly tricky to see what is going on although it looks nice as a one-liner

If you want to see a more transparent method you can start with empty array, loop through the array and add a property to the object for each element in the array.

```
const keys = ["J", "o", "h", "a", "n"];
const values = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1];
const myObj = {}

keys.forEach((key, index) => {
  myObj[key] = values[index]
})

console.log(myObj)
```

Here we go through the `keys` array, each element in the `keys` array is named `key`.

We then use the brack notation of an object to create a property and assign the value from the `values` array that is at the same index/location as the key element.

Comment: The way you explained this is great. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [Convert array to object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789406/convert-array-to-object-keys)

**Adding an extra iterator as third argument to track the index** will do the trick for you -

```js
const keys = ["J", "o", "h", "a", "n"];
const values = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1];
const result = keys.reduce((acc, key, iterator) => {
return {
 ...acc, [key]: values[iterator]};
},{});

console.log("result", result);
```